# Cognito adminInitiateAuth() method returning only accesstoken. it is not returning new refresh token

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Im using AWS Cognito for Authentication. Here is my code to generate new access token using the refresh token. But it is not returning new refresh token.

```
const pool = await getUserPool();
const params = {
  AuthFlow: "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
  ClientId: pool.clientId,
  UserPoolId: pool.userPoolId,
  AuthParameters: {
    REFRESH_TOKEN: token
  }
};
return await cognitoidentityserviceprovider
  .adminInitiateAuth(params)
  .promise();
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

When calling Cognito AdminInitiateAuth with a refresh token, you won't get a new refresh token, [you will get a new Access Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html). The refresh token is longer lived and used to get new access tokens without logging in again. But when the refresh token itself expires, the user needs to log in again.

> The authorization parameter, AuthParameters, is a key-value map where the key is "REFRESH_TOKEN" and the value is the actual refresh token. Amazon Cognito returns new ID and access tokens after your API request passes all challenges.
>
> If the refresh token is expired, your app user must re-authenticate by signing in again to your user pool.